# How to close all tabs that are on a certain webpage on storage change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to accomplish this by using a background page and using the .tabs api. I have tried

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        currentWindow: true,
        url: "*://www.facebook.com/*"
    }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs)
    })
})
```

with no success. The error I am getting is: [image: Error Message]

Am I doing something wrong? I do in fact have a facebook tab open, so I know that's not the problem. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your callback function, in your call to [`chrome.tabs.remove`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove). This function expects its first parameter to be an "integer or array of integer tabIds" but you are passing it an "array of Tab". You need to extract the tabIds from the Tabs array. For instance you can replace your callback function with this:

```
function(tabs) {
    var tabIds = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
       tabIds[i] = tabs[i].id;
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabIds);
})
```

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks.